# How Sitecore 9 Forms Module is featured for Multi-Site and Multi-Lingual?

Tags: multilingual, multisite, sitecore-forms

Recently while exploring Sitecore 9 Forms Module, came up with some queries hence thought of asking on community.

1. When we select a form, in the bottom right corner we see list of the
   items where the form is referred/used. How this will behave in a
   Multi-site implementation? As of now it just displays the name of
   the item (not even path), hence if we have 5 multisite implemented
   it will only list “Home” as an item and it will be difficult for the
   user to find out which “Home” it refers to until he copies the item
   ID and search in content tree.
2. If we are using any Language
   Conversion Tools like Clay Tablet, is it possible to send the Form
   for language conversion? Like some of my forms have guidelines and
   messages which need to be multi-lingual.

Comment: Avoid asking multiple questions at once. It makes it hard to give a complete answer..

Comment: Reduced the scope of the question by removing few queries.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the first question, if you hover over the display it shows the item title and path from the content node.

[image: Sample form reference when hovering.]

Answer (score 0):

Answering to your second query, you can submit the form for any translation tool, just you need to take care that when you translate, only "Title" field of the form element should be translated.

"Title" field of your form element say Password Confirmation or Dropdown field , should be only translated as rest all are either shared or not supposed to be translated.

In form editor , Title field will appear as "Label" and when you export the xml it generates a xml node with "Title", so don't get confused with them.

For Validation messages as well, you can submit for translation, also for messages, guidelines you can use "Text" field element in your form and submit for translation.

Hope this answers your second query.